# Parsing a Chess FEN

Tags: c++, parsing, chess

## What is an FEN?

Link to the Wikipedia page: [**Forsyth–Edwards Notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation)

An FEN is a very simple way of representing a chess position in a single line string. It contains the following data

- Which piece is placed where, and which squares remain empty
- Who is going to play the next move, white or black
- [Castling rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling#:%7E:text=Castling%20may%20only%20be%20done,attacked%20by%20an%20enemy%20piece.)
- [en-passant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant)
- Halfmove clock ( not required )
- Fullmove number ( not required )

<sup>Anyone unfamiliar with these terms, you won't need to know **what** they are</sup>

At the current stage, I don't need to worry about the last two points.

This is what the fen looks like at the very starting position of the chess game

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
```

Captial letters are white pieces, lowercase letters are black.

## How to parse it

Apologies for the lenghty question, but it will be very helpful to the reviewer if he/she understands the FEN completely

The main goal here is to decode this into a character array. The size will be equal to the number of square in a chess board(64).

Assume we are parsing to this array

```
char board[64];
```

We can assume this board to be
[image: chess]
The numbers on the squares are just the indexes. A chess FEN starts the square `A8` and ends in the square `H8`, this is perfect because those are the start and end indexes of our array

So if this is the FEN

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
```

the first few letters go `rnbq.../`. So the parsing should go as follows

[image: parse]

A `/` indicates going to the next row. Each time you see a numeric value, for example `8` here. 
You skip those number of squares ( which means you leave those squares as empty )So if you see a `5` at index `20`. Then `20, 21, 22, 23, 24` are left as empty squares and now we're at the 25th square.

## Special attributes

After the parsing of the board is over, the fen has a `' '` or an empty space indicating we're moving to the next attribute

So in our case

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
                                           ^
                                           Here is our first space 
Leaves us with
 w KQkq - 0 1
```

Each space says that now the fen will describe something else, the rest are split as follows
[image]
last two numeric values are not required as mentioned earlier

### turn

It will either be `w` or `b`,

- `w` - White will play next
- `b` - Black will play next

### castling

Each color has two types of castling rights, king and queen castle

- `k` Black's king side castle is possible
- `q` Black's queen side castle is possible
- `K` White's king side castle is possible
- `Q` White's queen side castle is possible

If any type of castle is **not possible**, then that letter will not be present here

### en-passant

- `-` means no en-passant in this position
- anything other than `-` will be the en-passant square

### examples

```
 b kK -
```

- Black to play
- only king side castles are possible for both colors
- no en-passant

```
 w KQq e4
```

- White to play
- White can castle king and queen side, black can castle only queen side
- en-passant is possible on square `e4`

I hope this explanation helps

## My implementation

I'll parse the fen into this class

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cctype> 

#define NB_SQ 64     // number of squares
#define NB_CASTLE 2  // number of castle types
#define NB_COLOR 2   // number of colors


enum Castle
{  king_side, queen_side };

enum Color
{ white, black };

class Chess
{
    private:
        Color turn; 
        std::string en_passant;
        char board[NB_SQ];
        bool castle_rights[NB_COLOR][NB_CASTLE];

    public:
        Chess();
        void parse_fen(const std::string&);
};
```

```cpp
Chess::Chess()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_SQ; i++) board[i] = '.'; // set all squares to be empty '.'

    for (int i = 0; i < NB_COLOR; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < NB_CASTLE; j++)
            castle_rights[i][j] = false; // all castle_rights are false by default
}

void Chess::parse_fen (const std::string& fen)
{
    const size_t size = fen.size();
    size_t iter = 0;
    int index = 0;

    // parse the board first
    for (; (iter < size) and (fen[iter] != ' '); iter++)
    {
        if (fen[iter] == '/')
            continue;


        if (isdigit(fen[iter]))
            index += (fen[iter] - '0'); // converts char digit to int. `5` to 5

        else
        {
            board[index] = fen[iter];
            ++index;
        }
    }

    turn = fen[iter + 1] == 'w' ? Color::white : Color::black;


    for (iter += 3; (iter < size )and (fen[iter] != ' '); iter++)
    {

        if (fen[iter] == 'k')
            castle_rights[Color::black][Castle::king_side] = true;

        else if (fen[iter] == 'K')
            castle_rights[Color::white][Castle::king_side] = true;

        else if (fen[iter] == 'q')
            castle_rights[Color::black][Castle::queen_side] = true;

        else if (fen[iter] == 'Q')
            castle_rights[Color::white][Castle::queen_side] = true;
    }


    en_passant = fen.substr(iter + 1, 3);

}
```

- Speed isn't a concern **at all** here. Anything that is slower, but better structured and more compact is definitely better since this function is performed at most 2-3 times and takes a few milliseconds anyway.
- Looking to avoid the extra noise in the function.

### test

Can test whether this works by printing out the board array

```cpp
void print_board()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_SQ; i++)
    {
        if (i % 8 == 0) std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << board[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output after parsing the default fen

```cpp
a.parse_fen("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1");
```

```
r n b q k b n r
p p p p p p p p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
P P P P P P P P
R N B Q K B N R
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **Handle malformed FEN**

  The code happily accepts `/9/`. It doesn't check that the rank spells out exactly 8 files. It doesn't check that the input spells out exactly 8 ranks. In both cases, hello buffer overflow.

  It also doesn't check that the piece letter makes sense (may be good for the fairy chess. but still ...).
- <strike>`fen.substr(iter + 1, 3);` looks strange, as it has no effect. Along the same line, I don't see en passant handling.</strike>
- The code assumes that there is exacly one space between board and turn, and between turn and castling rights. I am not sure that FEN standard mandates it. If it does not, allow multiple spaces; if it does, prepare to handle a malformed one.
- **More functions please**, aka **no naked loops**

  Every time you feel compelled to annotate a loop with a comment like

  ```
    // parse the board first
  ```

  consider to factor the loop out into a function with the proper name. Something along the lines of

  ```
    void Chess::parse_fen (const std::string& fen)
    {
        std::string::iterator it = fen.begin();
        it = parse_board(it);
        it = parse_turn(it);
        it = parse_castle_rights(it);
        ....
    }
  ```

Comment: Great! The last line captures the `en_passant`, I've tested it and it works, I made a last-second change and accidentally replaced the `en_passant = `, sorry about that. Can I edit the question and add it now? It wasn't intentional

Comment: I thought so. Please do. While you do it, also remove the semicolon from `void Chess::parse_fen (const std::string& fen);`

Answer (score 3):

- Use constant variables, not macros. (Perhaps `NB_COLOR` and `NB_CASTLE` could be added to the `enum`s).
- Use `enum class` instead of a plain `enum`.
- `en_passant` could be translated to the relevant index in the board. Perhaps use `std::optional`, or a named constant (e.g. `-1`) for the "no en-passant available" case.
- Use `std::array` instead of a plain array for utility reasons. e.g. in the constructor we could do `board.fill('.')`. It also makes copying much easier.
- Don't forget to initialize `turn` in the constructor.
- In addition to vnp's comments about parsing:

  Currently the parser skips over indices in the board (e.g. with `/8/`). If the board wasn't previously empty, these squares will still contain the pieces from before!! We must explicitly set these squares to be empty.

  It might be better to make `parse_fen` an alternate form of constructor instead.